# Why does using Format vs Right to apply padding cause estimated number of rows to dramatically change?

Tags: sql-server, performance, functions, collation, cardinality-estimates, query-performance

I was working on a query at work, that had a left join like

```
cast(cola as varchar) + '-' + right('000' + cast(colb as varchar), 3) = x
```

The actual execution plan for this query was fairly close, est 269 vs actually 475.

Changing the right +padding to use format(colb, '000') results in a a huge mis-estimate of the number of rows, off by at least 4 million, which causes the query to take 10-15 times as long.

I understand why a mis-estimate would cause a problem, but I don't understand why using Format would cause a less accurate estimate.

Comment: Casting to `varchar` *with no length* is also problematic, just in terms of accuracy, forget about performance. Try `DECLARE @x varchar = '269'; SELECT @x;`... also, why are you joining on some string comparison on both sides when you could perform a numeric comparison and skip all that expensive nonsense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things going on here:

1. Decreased performance (due to greatly increased logic reads)
2. Decreased accuracy of estimated number of rows

The factors involved are:

1. Indexed `VARCHAR` column, with a SQL Server Collation, compared to `NVARCHAR` data (Please note: this scenario is Collation-type specific: if the Collation was a Windows Collation then there would be no discernable degredation of performance. For details, please see "[Impact on Indexes When Mixing VARCHAR and NVARCHAR Types](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/07/10/impact-on-indexes-when-mixing-varchar-and-nvarchar-types/)" )
2. Non-deterministic built-in or SQLCLR function, OR T-SQL UDF (whether marked as deterministic or not)
3. Fragmented index (I had thought that it was merely stale stats that were the issue, but updating stats alone, even using `WITH FULLSCAN` has no effect)

The three factors noted above have been confirmed via testing (see below). Two of the three factors are easy enough to correct for:

1. Convert `NVARCHAR` values to `VARCHAR` if wanting to make use of an indexed `VARCHAR` column, OR change the column's Collation to be a Windows Collation.
2. Do a full `REBUILD` of the index(es). Doing an `ALTER INDEX ... REORGANIZE;` or `UPDATE STATISTICS ... WITH FULLSCAN;` by themselves does not seem to help (at least in terms of estimated row counts).
3. (optionally) Consider if a deterministic alternative is available (e.g. if `CASE / CONVERT` + `RIGHT` is more efficient than `FORMAT`, AND produces the same result, then by all means use `CASE / CONVERT` + `RIGHT` ; `FORMAT` can do some nifty things, but is unneccessary for left-padding).

Also keep in mind priorities. While having accurate estimated row counts is ideal, if they are close enough you will be fine. Meaning, don't feel the need to do extra work to get super-accurate estimated row counts if doing so won't give any real performance gain (especially since, depending on the level of fragmentation, the non-deterministic function sometimes has a more accurate row estimate!). On the other hand, changing the datatype (of the value being compared) or Collation is worth the effort as that will have a noticable positive impact. Then, doing a `REBUILD` of the index will get you close enough on the estimated row counts.

---

### Testing Method

I tested this by populated a local temporary table with 5 million rows of the "name" column from `sys.all_objects` (and using a Collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`), then creating a non-clustered index on the string column, and then adding another 100k rows to fragment the index.

I filtered on a `VARCHAR` literal, and then the same string literal but prefixed with an upper-case "N" to make it `NVARCHAR`. This isolated the issue of comparison value datatype.

I then filtered on the same literal value, but wrapped in a call to `FORMAT`. This isolated the issue of non-deterministic functions.

To confirm the behavioral effect of function determinism, I created two SQLCLR functions that did nothing more than return the passed-in values, but one is deterministic and the other is not. This makes it clear that the issue is determinism and not anything else happening with the function. I used SQLCLR because there does not seem to be an equivalent way of doing this in T-SQL. Even if the function is marked in the system as being deterministic (by creating the UDF using `WITH SCHEMABINDING`), the behavior will mirror that of non-deterministic functions (I did test this but did not include it below).

I used `SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;`, and checked the "Include Actual Execution Plan" option in SSMS.

After running the first set of tests, I executed:

```
EXEC (N'USE [tempdb]; UPDATE STATISTICS #Objects [IX_#Objects_Name] WITH FULLSCAN;');
```

and re-ran the tests. Minimal improvement on logical reads, and no change to estimated number of rows.

I then executed:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON #Objects REORGANIZE;
```

and re-ran the tests. No change to estimated number of rows.

I then executed:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON #Objects REBUILD;
```

and *finally* saw an improvement on both logical reads and estimated number of rows.

*Then*, I dropped the table, recreated it using `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC` as the Collation, and re-ran the tests as described above.

### Test Code

**SQLCLR Code**

The following code was used to create two scalar functions that do exactly the same thing: simply return the value passed-in. The only difference between the two functions is that one is marked as `IsDeterministic = true` and the other is marked as `IsDeterministic = false`.

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class ScalarFunctions
{
    [return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = 4000)]
    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
    public static SqlString PassThrough_Deterministic(
             [SqlFacet(MaxSize = 4000)] SqlString TheString)
    {
        return TheString;
    }

    [return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = 4000)]
    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = false, IsPrecise = true)]
    public static SqlString PassThrough_NonDeterministic(
             [SqlFacet(MaxSize = 4000)] SqlString TheString)
    {
        return TheString;
    }
}
```

**Test Setup**

```sql
-- DROP TABLE #Objects;
CREATE TABLE #Objects
(
  [ObjectID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Name] VARCHAR(128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                               -- Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC
);


-- Insert 5 million rows:
INSERT INTO #Objects ([Name])
  SELECT TOP (5000000) ao.[name]
  FROM   [master].[sys].[all_objects] ao
  CROSS JOIN [master].[sys].[all_columns] ac;

-- Create the index:
CREATE INDEX [IX_#Objects_Name] ON #Objects ([Name]) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);

-- Insert another 100k rows to fragment index and reduce accuracy of the statistics:
INSERT INTO #Objects ([Name])
  SELECT TOP (100000) ao.[name]
  FROM master.sys.all_objects ao
  CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns ac;
```

**The Tests (and results)**

Results key:

- Set "(A)" = SQL Server Collation ( `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` )
- Set "(B)" = Windows Collation ( `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC` )
- Each results comment: { before `REBUILD` } / { after `REBUILD` }
- "CS + CS" = Compute Scalar + Constant Scan

```sql
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
-- Total rows matching filter criteria: 2203

SELECT [ObjectID] FROM #Objects WHERE [Name] = 'objects';
-- (A) logical reads 13 (est. rows: 2125.67) / 9 (2203.15) Index Seek
-- (B) logical reads 13 (est. rows: 2019.74) / 9 (2203.25) Index Seek

SELECT [ObjectID] FROM #Objects WHERE [Name] = N'objects';
-- (A) logical reads 25159 (est. rows: 2125.67) / 23158 (2203.15) Index SCAN
-- (B) logical reads 13 (est. rows: 2019.74) / 9 (2203.25) Index Seek + CS + CS


SELECT [ObjectID] FROM #Objects WHERE [Name] = FORMAT(0, N'objects');
-- (A) logical reads 25159 (est. rows: 2433.23) / 23158 (2406.8) Index SCAN
-- (B) logical reads 13 (est. rows: 2307.69) / 9 (2208.75) Index Seek + CS + CS


SELECT [ObjectID] FROM #Objects WHERE [Name] =
                                      dbo.PassThrough_Deterministic(N'objects');
-- (A) logical reads 25159 (est. rows: 2125.67) / 23158 (2203.15) Index SCAN
-- (B) logical reads 13 (est. rows: 2019.74) / 9 (2203.25) Index Seek + CS + CS

SELECT [ObjectID] FROM #Objects WHERE [Name] =
                                      dbo.PassThrough_NonDeterministic(N'objects');
-- (A) logical reads 25159 (est. rows: 2433.23) / 23158 (2406.8) Index SCAN
-- (B) logical reads 13 (est. rows: 2307.69) / 9 (2208.75) Index Seek + CS + CS


SET STATISTICS IO, TIME OFF;


EXEC (N'USE [tempdb]; UPDATE STATISTICS #Objects [IX_#Objects_Name] WITH FULLSCAN;');

-- re-run tests

ALTER INDEX ALL ON #Objects REORGANIZE;

-- re-run tests

ALTER INDEX ALL ON #Objects REBUILD;

-- re-run tests
```

**Second Variation**

1. DROP table
2. re-create table using Windows Collation
3. re-run all tests in "The Tests" section above

Answer (score 4):

[`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) returns `nvarchar` which has a higher [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) than the compared varchar column. In addition the imprecise row count estimate, the implicit conversion of the compared `varchar` column to `nvarchar` will prevent indexes on that column from be used efficiently

Try casting the `FORMAT` result to `varchar`.

Comment: That solved the performance problem, still not sure why it would cause a mis-estimate of the row count, but changing that does fix it (it's still slightly less accurate, but the difference is negligible).

Comment: @jmoreno and Dan: regarding the statement "_implicit conversion of the compared varchar column to nvarchar will prevent indexes on that column from be used efficiently_", that is not exactly true. If it were, then the same implicit conversion to `VARCHAR` would have the same effect when using a Windows Collation. But it does not. Not being able to use the index is due to using a SQL Server Collation, which has a different ordering than when using either `NVARCHAR` (with either type of Collation) or a Windows Collation (with `VARCHAR`). Please see my answer for details.

Comment: Thanks for adding your more detailed answer, @SolomanRutzky. With a Windows collation, SQL Server is able to coerce a sargable expression of the unlike data types by computing the start and end values for the seek predicate using implict converversion plus `GetRangeThroughConvert`. This cannot be done with SQL Collations due to different sorting and comparison semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The remarks section for [FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) says

> The FORMAT function is nondeterministic.

Therefore, the query planner is confused about what to expect as result from this function. Maybe the non-deterministic behavior even keeps it from applying some optimizations, like caching intermediate results.